# Slow page load when looping results from a .json file

Tags: php, json, api, foreach

I am making a website for a gaming group and they would like to add their guild information on their website using the API the game developers provide. The APIs I'm working with are the following:

https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:1/item_details
https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/guild/:id/treasury

Right now, I have a table to show what items are in the treasury, how many, and how many are needed. It looks like this:

```
Item name     |     Quantity     |    Needed
-----------------------------------------------------
Iron Ore      |     150          |    1500
Mithril Ingot |     134          |    1000
etc...
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
// This gets a particular item.
function getItem($id) {
    $response = file_get_contents("https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/item_details.json?item_id=".$id);
    $response = json_decode($response, false);
    return $response;
}
// This gets the name if item 123
// echo getItem(123)->name;

// Begin table.
echo '<table class="table table-striped">';

$treasuryItem = file_get_contents('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/guild/B95A3B40-A764-4648-8EE6-39549E922A99/treasury?access_token=358AC6CB-0596-D64F-88D5-5CFA9AA27AAA273F3C6A-BC9E-47EE-AA28-63565C3EFEEE');
$treasuryItem = json_decode($treasuryItem);

foreach($treasuryItem as $key => $treasuryItem) {

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.getItem($treasuryItem->item_id)->name.'</td>';   // This is where I think the trouble lies.
    echo '<td>'.$treasuryItem->count.'</td>';
    echo '<td>';
        foreach($treasuryItem->needed_by as $key => $treasuryItem) {
            echo $treasuryItem->count.'<br />';
        }
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
```

As it stands now, it works and the info is displayed as I'd like it to be. My problem is that it takes a very long time for the page to load. I think the problem is that the function that calls the Item API file is being looped in the `foreach` statement. What alternative method can I use to prevent this from happening?

Comment: The json url is a problem , that is slow, not your code. if the url response is slow , it's obvious that php will wait for the response from it and then proceed. and more over you are calling the api url's again n again inside the foreach as well , which makes the response even slower

Comment: You can use something like AngularJS where you would bind the elements on your page to a model. The time till you see the results on the page would be the same but it wouldn't appear hanging. If the endpoint is slow your PHP output will be slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Link to the Items seems public, and i thing items wont change after set up. Maybe they change after a patch or so.

If you keep that in mind, you can hold the informations on your server.
Change the function to this:

```
function getItem($id,$forceDownload=false) {
   $response=null;
   $file = "item{$id}.json";
   if(!file_exists($file) || $forceDownload){
       $response = file_get_contents("https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/item_details.json?item_id=".$id);
       file_put_contents($file,$response);
   }
   if(!$response){
    $response = file_get_contents($file);
   }
   return json_decode($response, false);
}
```

Now for each Item a file would be saved e.g. `item123.json`, next time on pageload it will not be fetched from the WEB again, instead it uses the given file. That will be quit faster then.

If you want to reload all files from WEB use the second parameter `$forceDownload` and set it to `true`. Then all files will be loaded again.

And maybe set up a better dir like `"../items/item{$id}.json"`

Comment: This worked great for me - thanks! Is deleting the item{id}.json files from my server the same as changing false --> true? It forces the files to re-download, correct?